# Equivalence Relation questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ be the "between the same consecutive powers of 2" relation on $\mathbb{Z}^+$: $aRb \iff \exists k \in \mathbb{Z},(2^k \le a < 2^{k+1}) \wedge (2^k \le b < 2^{k+1})$

*a*. Explain why $7$ $\not R $ $9$

*b*. Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

*c*. List all of the elements of $[5]$

*d*. Use a particular counterexample to explain why *R* fails to be an equivalence relation if the definition is adjusted  as follows: $aRb \iff \exists k \in \mathbb{Z},(2^k < a < 2^{k+1}) \wedge (2^k < b < 2^{k+1})$

*e*. Use a particular counterexample to explain why *R* fails to be an equivalence relation if the definition is adjusted  as follows: $aRb \iff \exists k \in \mathbb{Z},(2^k \le a \le 2^{k+1}) \wedge (2^k \le b \le 2^{k+1})$

--

I'm particularly confused based on how the question "between the same consecutive powers of 2" for the definition is asked, so I was pretty lost trying to solve any of these. Tips/Answers for even 1 or 2 questions are helpful!! Thanks

Comment: Straightforward English translation of the definition: "Two numbers $a$ and $b$ are equivalent if there exists some integer $k$ such that both $a$ and $b$ are not less than $2^k$, and less than $2^{k+1}$." Does this help for the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they mean by 'between the same consecutive powers of 2' is that the powers of 2 can be seen as points to split the numberline into different intervals. That is, you have as powers of 2: 1,2,4,8,16, etc., which divides the integers into the intervals [1,2], [2,4], [4,8], etc.

If you look careful at the definition though, you see that the powers of 2 themselves are used as the start of each interval, and not as the end, so the intervals really become [1,2), [2,4), [4,8), etc.

Finally, for each interval we only consider the whole numbers that occur in those intervals, so we get the following groupings:

[1,2) becomes 1 by itself

[2,4) becomes 2 and 3

[4,8) becomes 4,5,6, and 7

Etc.

These groups are the equivalence classes defined by this equivalence relationship: aRb iff a and b are in the same group.

Ok, so this immediately answers the first question: 7 and 9 are not in the same group, so $7 \not R 9$

Oh, and for the second question you have to prove that it is actualy an equivalence relation: for this prove that the relation is reflexive,i.e. That every number is in the same group as itself (of course!), that it is symmetric, i.e. if a and b are in the same group, then b and a are in the same group (of course!), and that it is transitive, i.e. if a and b are in the same group, and b and c are, then a and c are (of course!)

I'll leave the rest to you

Comment: Thanks! I assume when it asks for the elements of [5] it means k = 5? so 32 through 63?

Comment: No. By $[5]$ they mean all the numbers that are in the same group that the number 5 is in. So that would be 4, 5, 6, and 7. Formally, $[i] = \{j|iRj\}$. So, $[5] = \{4,5,6,7\}$.